# MySQL encrypt fields and decrypt them with a password

Tags: encryption, databases, mysql, confidentiality

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to store some information into a DB that will only be accessible by specific users through a password.

So let's say I've got user X that stores something into the DB. That information is password encrypted and only once he enters the password can view the encrypted fields.

Any suggestions on how to achieve that? And is that even good enough protection to protect confidentiality?